# How can I determine the Culture / Locale from a TimeZone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, timezone, locale, globalization

I am writing a multi tenant system in MVC3 C# that stores a timezone against a user's record. This is used to present dates and times in the users timezone, as all Dates are stored in the DB as UTC.

I am wondering if I need to store a Locale with this TimeZone so I can format the dates appropriately.

I feel like I should be able to infer the locale from the TimeZone, but am not sure if there is a simple way I am missing.

Comment: do timezones and locales even match up 1:1?  im pretty sure different cultures often share timezones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one to one mapping from time zone to locale.

For example, Germany, France and Italy all share the same time zone, but have differing locales.
similarly, Greece, Finland, and Libya share time zones.

Of course, you have the reverse situation where a country spans several time zones (such as the USA) - and not all parts follow the same rules for observing daylight savings.